# SSH config on Windows when working under a HTTP proxy

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy

I'm trying to set up my `~/.ssh/config file` to connect on servers through the HTTP proxy my company is using, but it's falling everytime...
Does anyone know how to do this ?

I'm working on Windows 7, using the **Git Bash** tool, and here is my current `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ProxyCommand connect -H XX.XX.XX.XXXX:8080 %h 443
```

The command `ssh -T git@github.com -v` outputs :

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/name/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/name/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec connect -H XX.XX.XX.XXXX:8080 github.com 443
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1201653
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/gregv/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, my problem was actually the port set on 443, here is the correct `~/.ssh/config` file file that is working for me :

```
 Host github.com
     IdentityFile ~\.ssh\id_rsa
     ProxyCommand connect -H XX.XX.XX.XXXX:8080 %h %p
     ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: This still don't worked for me, I guess because is prohibed from my IT infrastructure setting create a tunnel